# Check whether the path exists on server or not in Java

Tags: java, sftp, jsch, file-exists

I'm creating a Java program in which I upload a file to a server on a particular path. I am using `jSch` for `sftp`.

So, before uploading the file, I want to check if the given directory exists on server or not.

```
if(path exists)
    //upload file to the location
else
    //create the directory and then upload the file.
```

How do I check the path exists or not?

**Note:** I am executing the code on a client that will check for the existence of a remote directory on a server. So please don't suggest `File.exists()`.

Comment: new File("<path>").exists();

Comment: @BrianRoach - OP wants to check existence of a file _on a server_ from a client program through ftp. `File.exists()` doesn't do the job.

Comment: It would appear that's the case, but honestly, its easy to read it incorrectly the way it's written. I still had to read it twice to see what you meant; I kept ignoring the first sentence.

Comment: I don't know why the question is downvoted???
I want to check the path on SERVER not on the local machine...
File.exists() doesn't work on the server...

Comment: You have a server component written in java to check the existence of path or you want client to check it ?

Comment: What library are you using to upload the file? Doesn't it provide any way to check if the path exist?

Comment: I don't know why the downvote, but I can guess: the way your question is worded suggests that a simple call to `File.exists()` or `File.isDirectory()` will do what you want. You should reword it to clarify that you want to emphasize that you need to execute code on a client that will check for the existence of a remote directory on a server.

Comment: @Sudhanshu - OP said the jSch library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reading the [Documentation for ChannelSftp](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html) it would appear you can just `lstat` the directory:

```
SftpATTRS attrs = channelSftp.lstat(path);
```

If that throws an exception, it doesn't exist. You can then use `channelSftp.mkdir(path)` to create it.

Comment: nice try but it doesn't return null if the path doesn't exists, but It throw an exception (no such file).

Comment: @AnkitLamba So ... there's your answer. The documentation is so terrible for the library I really couldn't tell, and a quick reading of his code didn't help (it's not exactly self documenting). (edited to change what result is)

Comment: @AnkitLamba - You can simply catch the exception to detect that the directory doesn't exist.

Comment: You may try to list the contents of parent directory using channelSftp.ls("<parent dir path>") and check if the desired folder exist.

Comment: @Sudhanshu Why? So you can add unnecessary string processing to your code for fun?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this library, but from this example code: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java.html it looks like you can use

```
ChannelSftp c = ..;
c.ls('<path>')
```

to retrieve the file, this should tell you whether it exists or not.