# Code in java to check if a directory exists or not on remote server

Tags: java, ssh, server, ftp

I am trying to write code in java to check if a directory exists or not on remote server. I have tried something mentioned on [Check whether the path exists on server or not in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21276775/check-whether-the-path-exists-on-server-or-not-in-java).

```
ChannelSftp channelSftp = new ChannelSftp();
SftpATTRS attrs = null;
try {
    String currentDirectory = channelSftp.pwd();
    System.out.println(currentDirectory);
} catch (SftpException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    attrs = channelSftp.stat("/x/web/STAGE2MA49/qatools/capturescripts_new");
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    System.out.println(" not found");
}
```

But the above code did work out. Below is the error stack

```
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.getHome(ChannelSftp.java:2443)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.getCwd(ChannelSftp.java:2452)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.pwd(ChannelSftp.java:2429)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:215)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:336)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:113)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:206)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:177)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.getHome(ChannelSftp.java:2435)
... 21 more
```

Comment: "But that did work out. getting null pointer exception" should probably be "...did **not** work out...". Anyway NullPointerException is [very common problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) but without [mcve] we can't help you with debugging.

Comment: My guess is that, since path was not found `SftpATTRS attrs = null;` stayed as `null` so later actions which involve it like `attrs.someMethod();` would end up as as call to `null.someMethod();` but `null` doesn't have any methods and throws NPE. Either execute such code which rely on `attrs` value inside `try` section which assigns non-null value to it, or each time you use it check if it is not null like `if(attrs != null)` OR don't wrap it in `try` and rethrow any exception you face to client who executed your code, then he will have to decide how to handle such exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

```
ChannelSftp channelSftp = new ChannelSftp();
```

You can't just construct a `ChannelSftp` object and expect it to work. You will need to create an SSH session to a remote server, then request an SFTP channel to run through the session.

The [question that you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21276775/13317) references an [example program](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java.html) which uses Jsch to make an SFTP connection to a remote server. I'll reproduce part of that here:

```
JSch jsch=new JSch();
...
Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
...
session.connect();
...
Channel channel=session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();
ChannelSftp c=(ChannelSftp)channel;
```

Using the JSCH API, you'd create a `Jsch` object, then use that to create a `Session`, then use the `Session` object to connect to the remote server. Assuming that worked, you can request an "sftp" channel operating through the session. That returns the `ChannelSftp` object that you need.